# Rails Form In General Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm know this is a newbie question just not sure what I'm missing and decided to post hear after my usual search through Google. I'm trying to post content to the database from a form in the footer of the application (for a newsletter) the view is therefore repeated throughout the application. Right now when I submit the form a new object is created in the database but all the fields are "NULL". It seems I need to put the *@newsletter* variable somewhere, I'm just not sure where.

**Partial I'm Rendering in the View**

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "newsletters", :action => "create"}, :method => "post", :id => "footer_email_form") do %>

    <%= text_field_tag :first_name, '', id: "footer_email_firstname" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :last_name, '', id: 'footer_email_lastname' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, '', id: 'footer_email_address' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit", :name => nil, id: 'footer_email_submit', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller (Create Action)**

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @newsletter = Newsletter.new(params[:newsletter])

      if @newsletter.save
          format.html { redirect_to 'pages#home', notice: 'Thank You for signing up for our newsletter' }
          format.json { render json: @newsletter, status: :created, location: @newsletter }
        else
          format.json { render json: @newsletter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :newsletters, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<%= form_for Newsletter.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The way your original form works the params are submitted like this:

```
params = {
  :first_name => 'A',
  :last_name  => 'B',
  :email      => 'C',
  # and so on...
}
```

Now if you do `@newsletter = Newsletter.new(params[:newsletter])` nothing will happen, because `params[:newsletter]` is `nil` and therefore all your attributes are going to be `nil` (and show up as `NULL` in the DB).

You should always have an eye on the development log. It's going to help you debug such errors.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Also thanks for the tip on the development log. As a newbie it's always nice to get tips.